# MySQL: Get last value of a non-grouped column in GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, magento, magento2

I'm running below query to join two tables and select a few columns. There are multiple values of points_balance but as I'm doing GROUP BY, I'm getting very first value of points_balance (which seems default). The use case is to fetch the last value of points_balance which will be the latest one in my case.

What updates below query requires for that? TIA

```
SELECT DATE(main_table.created_at) AS period, main_reward.customer_id,
main_reward.website_id,
SUM(IF(points_delta > 0, points_delta, 0 )) AS points_added,
SUM(IF(points_delta < 0  && is_expired = 0, ABS(points_delta), 0 )) AS points_used,
SUM(IF(points_delta < 0 && is_expired = 1, ABS(points_delta), 0 )) AS points_expired,
main_table.points_balance
FROM magento_reward_history AS main_table
INNER JOIN magento_reward AS main_reward ON main_table.reward_id = main_reward.reward_id
GROUP BY period, customer_id, website_id
```

Table schemas with some test data are:

**magento_reward**

| reward_id | customer_id | website_id | points_balance | website_currency_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75505 | 218501 | 1 | 71 |  |

**magento_reward_history**

| history_id | reward_id | website_id | store_id | action | entity | points_balance | points_delta | points_used | points_voided | currency_amount | currency_delta | base_currency_code | additional_data | comment | created_at | expired_at_static | expired_at_dynamic | is_expired | is_duplicate_of | notification_sent | is_processed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 313769 | 75505 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 949831 | 64 | 64 | 64 | 0 | 3.0000 | 3.0000 | USD |  |  | 2021-05-18 00:47:38 | 2022-05-18 00:47:38 | 2022-05-18 00:47:38 | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| 313770 | 75505 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 949832 | 109 | 45 | 45 | 0 | 5.0000 | 2.0000 | USD |  |  | 2021-05-18 00:50:18 | 2022-05-18 00:50:18 | 2022-05-18 00:50:18 | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| 313775 | 75505 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 949835 | 138 | 29 | 11 | 0 | 6.0000 | 1.0000 | USD |  |  | 2021-05-19 16:23:56 | 2022-05-19 16:23:56 | 2022-05-19 16:23:56 | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| 313783 | 75505 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  | 18 | -120 | 0 | 0 | 0.0000 | -6.0000 | USD |  |  | 2021-05-19 23:08:43 | 2022-05-19 23:08:43 | 2022-05-19 23:08:43 | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| 313784 | 75505 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 949840 | 71 | 53 | 0 | 0 | 3.0000 | 2.0000 | USD |  |  | 2021-05-19 23:08:46 | 2022-05-19 23:08:46 | 2022-05-19 23:08:46 | 0 |  | 0 |  |

For this data, I need to get 109 as points_balance for 2021-05-18, and 71 for 2021-05-19. Currently, I'm getting 64 and 138 which are the very first values for these dates.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, updated with table schemas and sample data

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment